# How to transform a xml node with commas to multiple nodes?

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I have a *1 time* transformation to do to a large XML file.

I have :

```
[stuff]
<items>string1,string2,string3,string4</items>
[other stuff]
```

I want to replace it with :

```
<itemList>
    <item>string1</item>
    <item>string2</item>
    <item>string3</item>
    <item>string4</item>
</itemList>
```

I'm hesitating between using a RegEx or XSL. I've been trying to go the regex way :

Search

```
^.*<items>(.*)</items>
```

Replace with

```
<itemList>\1</itemList>
```

I'm stuck at the "find comma and replace them by something". I'm not even sure it's doable...

How could I finish this RegEx? Should I go XSL instead?

Comment: it would certainly help if we knew what language or editor (regex "flavor") you were trying to use

Comment: I don't understand the connection between input **items** and output **itemList**. Do you want to split by comma separated values? Why only two string in the output?

Comment: @Code Jockey : I'm doing it in notepad++. Alternative software could work...

Comment: Kraz - Is there any reason you don't want to use the XSLT solution? I can help with usage if you'd like. You could download saxon (saxon-he is free) and I could give you a command line you could either run from the console or in a .bat file. It's super easy. :-)

Comment: No reason at all, the RegEx seemed easier at first, that's all. And yes. Did it with Saxon through the command line. :)

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad it worked for you. +1 for a good question.

Comment: A regex is a essentially a text-pattern-specification. You can also use them to parse patterns in text and specify a replacement expression to restructure the text matched by those patterns. The problem in your case comes down to sub-patterns (repetition of unknown quantity WITHIN another repetition). Matching sub-patterns is fairly straightforward, but parsing sub-patterns is typically not possible within a single expression. -- I would love to know if my solution worked for you - even if the XSL solution is preferred (it is definitely easier to read and reuse, even if it is more verbose :D )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use XSLT 2.0.

XML Input:

```
<doc>
  <stuff>sdfsadfsa</stuff>
  <items>string,string,string,string</items>
  <otherstuff>sdfasdfsaf</otherstuff>
</doc>
```

XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <itemList>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
        <item><xsl:value-of select="."/></item>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </itemList>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Output:

```
<doc>
   <stuff>sdfsadfsa</stuff>
   <itemList>
      <item>string</item>
      <item>string</item>
      <item>string</item>
      <item>string</item>
   </itemList>
   <otherstuff>sdfasdfsaf</otherstuff>
</doc>
```

If you don't have an XSLT 2.0 processor, I would suggest [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Because regexes are pretty bad at doing precisely this with a single pass, and I'm assuming the stressed "1 time" means a one time effort - and not that it must happen in one fell swoop (or only one expression), I would recommend two stages (and I'm using Perl syntax)

first stage (change the outer tags to the new tag container name):

```
s!<(/?)items>!<$1itemList>!
```

second stage (parse the listed items if they're in the containers):

```
s!,([^<,]+)(?=,|</itemList>)|(?<=<itemList>)([^<,]+)(?=,|</itemList>)!\n    <item>$1$2</item>!
```

These expressions will produce what you need, but may not produce EXACTLY the whitespace you showed in your example output. This is also assuming that the tags are as simple as your question shows... if you get much more complex (lots of different names, etc...), you should probably look into XSLT

If you want to have it formatted the same way as your example output, use this one last expression on a third pass, which will add in an extra carriage return in the right place:

```
s!(</item>)(</itemList>)!$1\n$2!
```

Comment: Sorry! edited pretty quickly, as it initially inserted the data into anchor (<a>) tags, not <item> tags, and also added a bit of explanation as to what each expression does

Comment: the syntax is also compatible with the .Net and Java flavors as well, though it will not work in Javascript - to use in a non-s!!-expression engine, just get rid of the "s!" at the beginning and split the remainder at the "!" symbols - you will get a match expression, a replace expression, and a zero-length string. use the first two to get your expressions.